# Optimizing memory usage of multi-threaded PHP application. Is APC or another memory caching technology appropriate?

Tags: php, memory-management, apc

I guess this question is similar in topic to [PHP cli Memory usage optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107262/php-cli-memory-usage-optimization), but that question was solved when the poster discovered a simple coding mistake.

I have a multi-threaded PHP (CLI) application that runs continuously. I am trying to optimize the memory usage because the amount of memory used by each thread limits the number of threads that I can run at any given time (since I have a finite amount of memory available). After some investigation, it seems that the MINIMUM amount of memory that each threaded process uses is around 1.3MB. Seems a bit high, but after some digging around it seems that PHP allocates memory in chunks of roughly 0.5MB. I doubt I can get my application lean enough to use less than 0.5MB, but I'd like to try. Even cutting the footprint by 10-20%, if possible, would be great.

One option I'm considering is using APC to cache some data in memory. This seems counter-intuitive as a technique for reducing memory, but currently I'm making pretty frequent calls to a MySQL db to store and retrieve data. Here is a small example:

```
<?php
function get_stored_token(){
    connect_db();

    $query_result = mysql_query("select token from tokens");
    if ($query_result == true){
           $query_result_array = mysql_fetch_row($query_result);
           $token = $query_result_array[0];
           unset($query_result, $query_result_array);
           return $token;
    }
    else {
           echo "Problem with query to get stored token!\n";
    }
}
```

It seems there is a lot of memory overhead with using MySQL in such a way. This is confirmed by a call to `pmap -d PID | grep mysql`, where especially `libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0` was using a lot of memory. So perhaps a simple technique to cache key/value pairs in memory would actually be lighter in terms of memory? I don't have experience with this, however, so I'd like to hear feedback on this idea before experimenting more with APC (or some other caching technology).

Any other ideas on how to optimize memory usage in PHP would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use memcached for the db interaction which would speed up the threads processing ability quite alot. It may not reduce overall memory usage but it would increase execution speed so you should be able to open and close threads more rapidly or better cross schedule threads so not everythings going on at once.
If 2 processes that took 1 min each now take 30 seconds each then both processes can double up on memory usage and only use 30 seconds each now still overall a minute but faster execution.

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using a WHERE term? in SQL this part determine how many rows will be loaded to the php , if you are looking for the first/last id in the DB use SQL function for this. in general passing SQL data to php will consume Memory.

i think if this a table that is loded only for select for all users and is not modify by the users Memcahe will be usefull for this . [Memcashe PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

Comment: In this particular table, there is only one row. So I'm not sure a where clause would help. But I can try it out...